# IntelliJ idea doesn't show me the spring initializr

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

could you help me please?

I've intall the lastest Intell iDEA version 2020.1.1 comunity but Whent I try to creat a new project with Spring it doesn't show me Spring[image]

I looked for it in the installed and disabled plugins and nothing appears about it.

How can I install it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is not support for Spring in that version dude, but you can user https://start.spring.io/ to create the project with its depencencis , also you can use the SpringTools suite Ide based on eclipse but you really want use IntelliJ iDea https://start.spring.io/ is your best option is almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

That is part of IntelliJ Ultimate edition

You would require to go to https://start.spring.io

Select modules and options and download zip, and import in intellij community

Answer (score 1):

**Spring is not supported in the community version of IntelliJ. You need to get the Enterprise (Ultimate) Edition.**

Refer here : https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Better use -> **Spring Tools Suite 4 Eclipse IDE**. (Free and recommended one).